# R - Decreasing memory usage of using caret to train a random forest

Tags: r, r-caret

I am trying to create a random forest given ~100 thousand inputs. To accomplish them, I am using `train` from the caret package with `method = "parRF"`. Unfortunately, my machine with 128 GBs of memory still runs out. Therefore, I need to cut down on how much memory I use.

Right now, the training method I am running is:

```
> trControl <- trainControl(method = "LGOCV", p = 0.9, savePredictions = T)
> model_parrf <- train(x = data_preds, y = data_resp, method = "parRF",
                     trControl = trControl)
```

However, because each forest is kept, the system quickly runs out of memory. If my understanding of `train` and `randomForest` is correct, each random forest made stores about `500 * 100,000` doubles at the very least. Therefore, I would like to throw away the random forests I no longer need. I tried passing the `keep.forest = FALSE` into `randomForest` using

```
> model_parrf <- train(x = data_preds, y = data_resp, method = "parRF",
                       trControl = trControl, keep.forest = FALSE)
Error in train.default(x = data_preds, y = data_resp, method = "parRF",  : 
  final tuning parameters could not be determined
```

In addition, this warning was thrown repeatedly:

```
In eval(expr, envir, enclos) :
  predictions failed for Resample01: mtry=2 Error in predict.randomForest(modelFit, newdata) : 
  No forest component in the object
```

It seems that for some reason, caret requires the forests to be kept in order to compare models. Is there any way I can use caret with less memory?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that, if you use `M` cores, you need to store the data set `M+1` times. Try using less workers.

Comment: The data is comparatively small. There are 9 doubles and a factor per row, so I would expect the data frame for the predictors and the response vector to be under 10 MB together. Does using multiple cores also increase the number of trees kept? It seems like it would if you are using different cores to train models with different tuning parameters but that there wouldn't be a significant change if you were training a single forest across multiple cores.